# Custom segue from app delegate

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I'm trying to perform a segue from my `AppDelegate`. I know I can't actually perform a segue from the `AppDelegate`, since a segue is a transition from one scene to another, so I instantiate the two `ViewControllers` concerned in my `AppDelegate`

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let loadingViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("loadingViewController") as UIViewController
let loginViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("loginViewController") as UIViewController
let mainViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("mainViewController") as UIViewController
```

Then later, I try to `loadingViewController.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueToLogin", sender: self)` where `segueToLogin` is a custom segue identifier in my storyboard

[image]

The error I get (which doesn't crash the app) is

```
Tacklebox[27258:1016738] Warning: Attempt to present <Tacklebox.LoginViewController: 0x7fd8a9646bd0> on <Tacklebox.LoadingViewController: 0x7fd8a943d940> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

and the end result is I stay on the `sourceViewController`, `loadingViewController`.

Comment: I tried removing the custom segue and just use the default `Show` segue. Now I don't get any warnings, the vc just doesn't move at all - no segue. 

So I guess my question is more of a "why is my `performSegueWithIdentifier` from my `instantiated ViewControllerWithIdentifier` in my `AppDelegate` not working?"

Comment: Is there any code in `launchOptions:` in your App Delegate? Meaning you're just using the default storyboard to go to the first view controller?

Comment: And you've put that `performSegue` code in the App Delegate? (Basically the problem has to do with you using a view controller instance that's not actually on the stack, but I'm trying to figure out the best way to fix your code.)

Comment: I don't think I have any `launchOptions` specified. Yes, it is in the `AppDelegate`, [here's](http://pastebin.com/ygrahx5p) my entire `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you've created these view controllers in the App Delegate, but since you haven't used those particular instances to navigate between views, those view controller instances aren't the same view controllers actually on the stack; thus the error saying the `LoadingViewController` instance you're trying to segue to "is not in the window hierarchy."

You're going to have to get the instance of the active `LoadingViewController`. Since that view controller from which you're performing a segue is bound to be (i.e. supposed to be) visible and since (as indicated by your Storyboard), the `rootViewController` is a `UINavigationController`, try this to access the current `LoadingViewController` in the navigation hierarchy:

```
let navigationController = self.window?.rootViewController as UINavigationController
let loadingViewController = navigationController.visibleViewController as LoadingViewController
loadingViewController.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueToLogin", sender: self)
```

Comment: Works <3. I have a question about creating this constants (like navigationController, loadingViewController, etc.) in this way. When you make those calls are you creating new instances of these objects or just referencing them off the storyboard?

Comment: @AndrewSB I just replaced the second line of my code to simplify things a tiny bit... Could you do me a favor and check to see if that still works for you?

Comment: @AndrewSB No you're not creating new instances in the code I wrote out by referencing the current instances on the navigation stack. In your original code though, you were creating new instances. I'll clarify that in my answer...